# Kendo grid hide delete button

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I want to hide delete button in some rows with certain conditions. I have checked the following link but it is still not working well.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-edit-and-delete-button-based-on-the-status-of-each-record

Their code like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  $(".k-grid-cancel").on("click", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("trigger");
        $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").trigger("dataBound");
    });
  })
}
```

The problem is when you changed any items in the popup edit window, the delete button will show up on the original gray out area. Although you click the cancel button, it will disappear. But if you click the right up corner [x] to close the popup edit window, the delete button will stay there.

Any body know there is any new update for the kendo grid conditional button?

Thanks

Comment: I have added the kendo window close event to trigger the dataBound also. It is OK now to close the window. But the delete button in the middle of editing is really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add an event in the grid as

```
.Events(ev => 
 {
       ev.Cancel("onEditCancel");
 })
```

And then on js

```
function onEditCancel(e) {
    e.sender.cancelChanges();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by using **onDataBinding** event of KendoGrid.

```
function onChange(arg) {
                    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
                        return $(item).text();
                    });

                    console.log("Selected: " + selected.length + " item(s), [" + selected.join(", ") + "]");
                }

                function onDataBound(arg) {
                  console.log(arg);
                    console.log("Grid data bound");
                }

                function onDataBinding(arg) {
                    console.log(arg);
                    console.log("Grid data binding");
                }

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 350,
                        change: onChange,
                        dataBound: onDataBound,
                        dataBinding: onDataBinding,
                        selectable: "multiple cell",
                        pageable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "ProductName",
                                title: "Product Name"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "UnitPrice",
                                title: "Unit Price",
                                format: "{0:c}"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "UnitsInStock",
                                title: "Units In Stock"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/HuTpj/68/ and see the console for events trigger while loading the grid.

Comment: It does not work. It looks like the beginning of the binding, not the middle of editing. I tried to use .change event, but it does not work either.